# Making equal arguments of sine or cosine function

Tags: waves, interference, mathematics

I have trouble understanding one common type of inference about waves. In physics textbooks, frequently when text is about waves I see inference where arguments of trigonometric functions made equal knowing that their trigonometric functions are equal. Here is example:

Lets imagine ray that is split in two. Lets imagine that they have different path lengths. Lets imagine that we combine them again. Now we want to know their phase difference.

Why this inference is valid:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
y=\sin(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}x+\phi)\\
y=\sin(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(x+\Delta L))
\end{array}
\right. 
\implies \phi=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\Delta L
$$?

As far as I understand, I can:

$\sin(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(x+\Delta L))=\sin(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}x+\phi)$ so

$$
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(x+\Delta L)=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}x+\phi+2\pi n, n \in Z\\
\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(x+\Delta L)=\pi-(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}x+\phi)+2\pi n, n \in Z
\end{array}
\right. 
\iff
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\Delta L=\phi+2\pi n, n \in Z\\
\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\Delta L=\pi-\phi+2\pi n, n \in Z
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: Since both are equal to y, they need to be equated. Since both are functions of wine, the arguments of the sine functions need to be equated next. After that it is as you have worked out.

Comment: I have trouble understanding why it is valid to equate arguments of sine.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are right that all you can really conclude is that $\phi=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} \Delta L + 2 \pi n$ for $n$ being an integer. In other words, if you split a sinusoidal wave into two paths and recombine them, you will get constructive interference if the two path lengths are the same, *or* if they differ by an integer number of wavelengths. But normally we ignore the $2\pi n$ since it has no impact on the results.

Comment: Why do you give special preference to sin(x)? If it were y=x^2 and y= 4x-3, would you have any problems with equating them? @AlexAlex

Answer (score 0):

> I have trouble understanding why it is valid to equate arguments of sine.

You are not equating the arguments, you are equating the result of sine on those values.

While

$$\sin(\pi-\theta)=\sin(\theta)$$

this is not true for $\cos()$ because

$$\cos(\pi-\theta)=-cos(\theta)$$

> Now we want to know their phase difference.

Note that the phase difference is something you **add** to the argument.  When you set $\sin(\theta)=\sin(\pi-\theta)$ your are *not* finding the phase as it is defined as additive $\sin(\theta)=\sin(\theta\mathbf{+}\phi)$

While textbooks sometimes play a little fast and loose with the math, you cannot in general use a sine function alone for a wave like that and you would be using a more general version like this :

$$y=A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)$$

This is because the simple wave equation is a second order differential equation and both sine and cosine are solutions and a general solution would be a linear combination.  So the period of that will be $2\pi$ and you cannot use $\pi-x$ on that general function and get the same result for amplitude.

The texbook writers don't explicitly write out this (always) which is a mistake (IMO) as it leads to confusion like yours.

Comment: Can you prove the statement that is in question using predicate logic? I am questioning why we can infer that arguments of sine or cosine are equal.

Comment: @AlexAlex No one is saying the arguments are equal.  It's the resulting amplitude (function value) that is equal.  We are in fact saying that different arguments produce the same amplitude for a particular difference (the phase difference).

Comment: I don't understand your argument.

Comment: All we're doing is finding values for $\delta$ which give $y(x)=y(x+\delta)$.  I don't think anyone understands what proof you require of this (nor your insistence on "predicate logic" - I cannot recall anyone ever requiring this for such a purpose).

Answer (score 0):

If a wave (with a sharply defined frequency) is split, sent on different paths, and recombined, the phase difference (in cycles) will be the path difference / wavelength (and may be more than several cycles). Multiplying by 2π puts it into radians.

Comment: I know that. I am interested in proving argument validity not in argument itself. I am interested in deriving it using predicate logic.